# Not able to populate data table using jquery datatable by passing JSON data from php file

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to populate Data Table using data table plugin from Jquery and passing JSON data from PHP. However i am getting invalid JSON error. I had validated my json using JSON lint and it validates it sucessfully

My code is shown below:

```
//SQL query to get data from Database

$sql_fabentry="select f.fabrication_date as date,concat(w.workstage_name,':',f.fabricator_remarks)"
            . " as workstage_entry,u.user_name from fabrication_record f,workstage w,"
            . "users u where f.workstage_id=w.workstage_id and u.user_id=f.fabricator_id "
            . "and f.subsystem_id='$subsystem_id_session' and f.cp_no IS NULL";


    $sql_qcentry="select f.qc_date as date,concat(r.remark,':',f.qc_remarks)"
            . " as workstage_entry,u.user_name from fabrication_record f,remarks r,"
            . "users u where f.qcremarks_id=r.remark_id and u.user_id=f.qcinspector_id "
            . "and f.subsystem_id='$subsystem_id_session' and f.cp_no IS NULL";

//db_select function return an associative array
//result from both queries will always return same number of rows
$results_fabentry=$db->db_select($sql_fabentry);
$results_qcentry=$db->db_select($sql_qcentry);

 //Here iam trying to combine the two arrays in one array with alternating 
 //rows from each array

$count1=count($results_fabentry);
$i=0;
$j=0;
$result=array();
while($i<$count1){
    $result[$j]['date']=$results_fabentry[$i]['date'];
    $result[$j]['workstage_entry']=$results_fabentry[$i]['workstage_entry'];
    $result[$j]['user_name']=$results_fabentry[$i]['user_name'];

    $result[$j+1]['date']=$results_qcentry[$i]['date'];
    $result[$j+1]['workstage_entry']=$results_qcentry[$i]['workstage_entry'];        
    $result[$j+1]['user_name']=$results_qcentry[$i]['user_name'];
    $i++;
    $j+=2;
}


$results=["sEcho=>1",
            "iTotalRecords"=>count($result),
            "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>($result),
            "aaData"=> $result];

echo json_encode($results);
```

I have verified the JSON data in $ result and it is valid. If a remove the while loop and try following it works:

```
$results=["sEcho=>1",
            "iTotalRecords"=>count($results_fabentry),
            "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>($results_fabentry),
            "aaData"=> $results_fabentry];

echo json_encode($results);
```

Can anyone please explain what am i doing wrong?

Comment: did yu print both json and see whats the difference?

Comment: The difference is only in the data. As JSON $result will contain data from both the queries. Even with an empty while loop following will not work: $results= 
          ["sEcho=>1",
            "iTotalRecords"=>count($results_fabentry),
            "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>($results_fabentry),
            "aaData"=> $results_fabentry];

            echo json_encode($results);

Comment: Can you please share the JSON that is not working? Is it DataTables that gives you the error? Can you please share the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by replacing the while loop with foreach loop. I used the following code and its working fine

```
$result = [];

$i=0;
$j=1;
foreach($results_fabentry as $result_fabentry){
    $result[$i]['date']=$result_fabentry['date'];
    $result[$i]['workstage_entry']=$result_fabentry['workstage_entry'];
    $result[$i]['user_name']=$result_fabentry['user_name'];
    $result[$i+1]['date']="0";
    $result[$i+1]['workstage_entry']="0";
    $result[$i+1]['user_name']="0";

    $i+=2;
}

foreach($results_qcentry as $result_qcentry){

    $result[$j]['date']=$result_qcentry['date'];
    $result[$j]['workstage_entry']=$result_qcentry['workstage_entry'];        
    $result[$j]['user_name']=$result_qcentry['user_name'];

    $j+=2;
}

$results=["sEcho=>1",
            "iTotalRecords"=>count($result),
            "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>($result),
            "aaData"=> $result];

echo json_encode($results);
```